# Need to export full product feed from Hybris for Google shopping

Tags: csv, export, sap-commerce-cloud, google-shopping

Im very new to hybris and need to export the full online product category in CSV to import to Shoptimise for Google shopping. If anyone knows how to go about this and the script that needs to be written to carry out the task that would be very helpful

I haven't tried anything so far, so any direction will be helpful